# Hierarchical Data Model with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, data-modeling

[image]

Recently I come across a schema model like this
Structure looks exactly the same, i just renamed with Entity name like Table (*)
Starting from Table C, all the tables are having close to 200 Columns, from C to L

Reason for posting this is like, I never come across structure like this before, if anyone who have already experienced like this or worked similar or more complex than this please do share your idea,

1. Having a structure like this is good or bad, and why?
2. Assume we need to have API to save data for the table structure like this,
   how to design the API
3. How we are going to manage the Transactional across all these tables
4. In service code, there are few cases where we might need to get data from these table and transfer to external system.
   Catch here is, external system is accepting the request in the flatten structure not in the hierarchy which we have as mentioned above. If this data needs to be transferred to external system, how can we manage marshaling and un marshaling
5. Last but not least, API which is going to manage the data like this can be consumed atleast 2K a day.

   What is your thought on this, I don't know exactly why we need it, it needs a detailed discussion and we need to break up the things.

If I consider Spring Data JPA, Hibernate. What are all things i need to consider,

More Importantly, all these tables row values will be limited based on the the ownerId/tenantId, so the data needs to be consistent across all the tables.

Comment: Please don't format text as code, it's not readable, have you tried yourself to read your question?

Comment: @perissf. I didn't check after posting, I edited it again. Pasting the Image makes the content below as CODE. If it's still not clear do let me know. I will try to re iterate the question to reach broader audience.

Comment: Ok, now the formatting is fine. Could you please expand the point 1 in order to make it not an opinable question? Explain better the structure shown in the picture, and don't ask if it's good or bad, instead ask if the structure has some features or not (which features?). Add code. And don't ask many questions in one post. Only one

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment on the general aspect of the structure as that is pretty domain specific and one would need to know why this structure was chosen to be able to say if it's good or not. Either way, you probably can't change this anyway, so why bother asking if it's good or not?

Having said that, with such a model there are a few aspects that you should consider:

- When updating data, it is pretty important to update only columns that really changed to avoid index trashing and allow the DB to use spare storage in pages. This is a performance concern that usually comes up when using Hibernate with such models as Hibernate usually updates all "updatable" columns, not just the dirty ones. There is an option to do dynamic updates though. Without dynamic updates, you might produce a few more IOs per update and thus keep locks for a longer time which affects the overall scalability.
- When reading data, it is very important not to use join fetching by default as that might result in a result set size explosion.